# Lots of errors when I want to dockerize my vuejs app

Tags: typescript, docker, macos, vue.js, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and I need to dockerize my application so that my team can develop with me easily and efficiently without installing a whole environment.

So I followed the tutorial in the official Vue.js documentation to dock my application and it didn't work. I have the impression that there is a problem with my processor since I have an apple silicon M1 pro chip, I don't know.

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN npm install -g http-server

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

---

My Error :

```
"GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.4 Safari/605.1.15"
(node:1) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
```

---

[My Error in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0FtQ.png)

Comment: change this command to `COPY package.json ./`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: I tried and I always get the same error. It seems to me that the * allows to recover also the package-lock in addition it is all, I don't think that it poses problem